# Включить чекбоксы исходя из данных в файле

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

Есть массив данных, полученный из .ini файла и переведенный в JSON, такого вида:

```
{"Box":1,"Case":1,"CPU":1,"RAM":1,"PSU":1,"SoundCard":1,"NetCard":1,"Monitor":1,"Name":"Template2"}
```

$components - массив, возвращенный из файла, имеет вид:

```
<?php
return [
'Box' => 'Системный блок',
'Case' => 'Корпус',
'CPU' => 'Процессор',
'RAM' => 'Оперативная память',
'MB' => 'Материнская плата',
'Video' => 'Видеокарта',
'SSD' => 'Твердотельный накопитель',
'HDD' => 'Жёсткий диск',
'DVD' => 'Оптический привод',
'PSU' => 'Блок питания',
'SoundCard' => 'Звуковая карта',
'NetCard' => 'Сетевая карта',
'Monitor' => 'Монитор',
'Keyboard' => 'Клавиатура',
'Mouse' => 'Мышь',
'Telephone' => 'Телефон',
'UPS' => 'ИБП',
];
```

Файл загрузки данных:

```
<?php
$names = array();
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . "/../templates/*.ini") as $file) {
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    $names[] = $array['Name'];
}

$data = array();
foreach (glob(__DIR__ . "/../templates/*.ini") as $file) {
    $array = json_decode(file_get_contents($file), true);
    $fileName = basename($file, '.ini');
    $data[] = $array;
}
$jsonData = json_encode($data);
```

Есть select с option'ами:

```
  <div id="templateDiv">
                <select name="templates">
                    <option value="default" selected>Выберите шаблон</option>
                    <?php foreach ($names as $name):?>
                        <option value=<?=$name?>><?=$name?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <hr>
                    <ul class="checkbox">
                        <?php foreach ($components as $component => $nameRu):?>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" name="components[]" value=<?=$component?> id=<?=$component?>> <label for=<?=$component?>><?=$nameRu?></label></li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <hr>
        </div>
```

Соответственно, при создании чекбоксов, value и id им задаются по типу: `Box, Case, CPU`

```
<?php foreach ($components as $component => $nameRu):?>
 <li><input type="checkbox" name="components[]" value=<?=$component?> id=<?=$component?>> <label for=<?=$component?>><?=$nameRu?></label></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Как реализовать включение флажка в чекбоксе, сравнив имя ключа в JSON с именем чекбокса?

Comment: Как понять включить? Если поставить флаг чекбоксу то это атрибут `checked="checked"`

Comment: Насчёт checked понятно, я не понимаю, как реализовать алгоритм: Если в json есть такое название, как у чекбокса, то включить его. Извиняюсь, за такие глупости, конечно, но я абсолютный ноль в js/jquery, а сделать требуют.

Comment: При переборе $components делать проверку `array_key_exist($array, $key)` если ключ существует показывать атрибут? Это если я правильно понял что если ключ из массива 1 есть в массиве 2 то надо показать флаг в чекбоксе?

Comment: Попробую поточнее объяснить. Из массива $components генерируются чекбоксы, с точно такими же названиями, как и ключи в JSON. В Select есть option'ы, в которых название шаблона. Когда я выбираю определенный option, мне нужно чтобы в чекбоксах поставились флажки с такими же названиями, какие ключи были в json'e

Comment: Ну так это на JS нужно делать и при чём здесь PHP? Приведите пример пары JSON и HTML разметку (без PHP вкраплений). И правильно ли я понимаю, что ключи в JSON у всех одинаковые и различаются лишь значением (1,0)?

Comment: Добавил больше кода из связанных файлов и пояснений, надеюсь это поможет найти решение. Значения роли не имеют, они были добавлены, чтобы можно было сделать array_flip. В JSON добавлены только те ключи, которые были сохранены в .ini файл.